# To bring onClick out of the map function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

`onClick` event applies to all the elements, I have tried putting out the click event but not able to resolve it.

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { itemsFetchData,toggleDiv } from '../actions/sidenavaction';

class SideNavItem extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchData('http://58f5d2ccc9deb71200ceecef.mockapi.io/nav');
    }


    render() {

        var Nest=function(par) {
            const numbers = par.itemized;
            const listItems = numbers.map((number) => <li key={number.sid}>{number.svalue}</li>);
            return (<ul>{listItems}</ul>);
        };



        if (this.props.hasErrored) {
            return <p>Sorry! There was an error loading the items</p>;
        }

        if (this.props.isLoading) {
            return <p>Loading…</p>;
        }

        return (
            <ul>{this.props.items.map((item) =>         
                <ul key={item.id}  onClick={this.props.toggleDiv.bind(this,item.id)}><a href="#">
                {item.value}</a>
                {item.sub && <div style={{display: this.props.hidden ? 'block' : 'none'}}><Nest itemized={item.sub} /></div>}           
                </ul>               
            )}
            </ul>
        );          
    }
}
```

How can I move my onClick function out of the map function

---

#### Update

The Action

```
export function toggleDiv(id){
    return {
      type: 'TOGGLE_DIV',
      id:id
    };
}
```

Reducer for onClick

```
export function toggleDivReducer(state = { hidden: true}, action){
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'TOGGLE_DIV':
            return Object.assign({}, state, {hidden: !state.hidden,id: action.id});
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: An inline function might work for you.
`<ul key={item.id}  onClick={(e) => this.props.toggleDiv(item.id)}>`

Comment: What is the behaviour that u expect

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want to add `onClick` event to one particular element inside the map or you want to stop the event propagation to the parent elements?

Comment: @Shubham Khatri Actually onClick is getting applied to all the elements within map function , I want it to be applied only on the element clicked, not to all the elements, I tried moving the onClick outside of map function but was not able to

Comment: Change the `ul` here `<ul key={item.id}  onClick=` to `li` and change the onclick to `onClick={e => this.props.toggleDiv(item.id)}`. I am still not sure this is what you are referring as issue.

Comment: The issue is the list which I get out of the map function , on clicking on any one value the click event gets applied to all the other value as well, I think I have tried these things but I haven't changed ul to li , okay I'll try this out,and let u know,THANKS :)

Comment: @Aruna One more doubt I had as to what is the difference between onClick={e => this.props.toggleDiv(item.id)} and onClick={this.props.toggleDiv.bind(this,item.id)}, apart from the former being ES6 syntax

Comment: @TharakaWijebandara,@Aruna,@Shubham Khatri I have tried out the onClick={e => this.props.toggleDiv(item.id)} but now also the click event is getting applied to all the elements, any leads

Comment: @Michael Peyper ,@Panther any help:)

Comment: @Harsh I'm still confused as to what the issue is and what the expected behaviour is. Can you add the `toggleDiv` action creator and associated reducer(s)?

Comment: @MichaelPeyper, sure

Comment: I have the list which I get from` this.props.items.map((item) =>{})`
1SNOMEDs
   1.1 Lab/Diagnostics
   1.2 Medication
   1.3 Procedure
   1.4 Sign/Symptoms
   1.5 Disease Disorder
   1.6 Anatomical Site
 2 Medication                                                                              
 3 Lab
 4 Radiology/Diagnostic
 5 ICD9/ICD10
 6 CPT/HCPCS
 7 Patient Safety Terms
 8 Quality Measures
 9 Identified Annotation
10 Measurement Mention
    10.1 Ranges
    10.2 Roman Numeral
    10.3 Date & Time
    10.4 Context

Comment: Now the issue is by default the nested navigation are hidden when the list loads and it happens as expected , but when I click on any of the navs say suppose 1or2or3or4or5or6or7or8or9or10 the
 nested values for 1(SNOMED) and 10(Measurement Mentions) also opens , click is triggered on all the values

Comment: @MichaelPeyper I have edited the main post and added the Action and Reducer, and please refer to the above two comments as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so the issue is in the `toggleDivReducer` and the way `this.props.hidden` is used in the component

```
export function toggleDivReducer(state = { hidden: true}, action) { 
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE_DIV':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {hidden: !state.hidden,id: action.id});
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and

```
{item.sub && <div style={{display: this.props.hidden ? 'block' : 'none'}}><Nest itemized={item.sub} /></div>}
```

Firstly, the ternary seems to be backwards (`display: 'block'` when hidden?), so for simplicity sake, I'll assume this is the case and talk about showing the items when `hidden` is `false` in this answer.

You haven't provided the `mapStateToProps` function but I can only assume it looks something like

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    items: [/* from some other reducer */],
    hidden: state.toggleDivReducer.hidden
  }
}
```

The issue is that it doesn't care which item id is hidden or not, if the `hidden` flag toggles, all of the sub items will be shown (the behaviour you are observing).

Now there are 2 ways a can envision the components should behave:

1. Sub-menus can be toggled open independently
2. Toggling a sub-menu will close other already open sub-menus

---

#### Solution 1.

Change the `toggleDivReducer` to be like

```
export function toggleDivReducer(state = {}, action){ 
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE_DIV':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {[action.id]: !state[action.id]});
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This stores the visible state against an id. **Note:** It is important to flip the logic to store `visible` rather than `hidden` as we want the default to be hidden, but the default value will be `false` (as there are no ids in the state initially.

Then change `mapStateToProps` to be like

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    items: [/* from some other reducer */],
    visibleItems: state.toggleDivReducer
  }
}

And then the usage to be like

```
{item.sub && <div style={{display: this.props.visibleItems[item.id] ? 'block' : 'none'}}><Nest itemized={item.sub} /></div>}
```

---

#### Solution 2.

Change the `toggleDivReducer` to be like

```
export function toggleDivReducer(state = { hidden: true }, action){ 
  switch(action.type) {
    case 'TOGGLE_DIV':
      return Object.assign({}, state, {hidden: !state.hidden && state.id == action.id, id: action.id});
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

This will only set the hidden flag to false if it was the previously toggled item.

Then change `mapStateToProps` to be like

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    items: [/* from some other reducer */],
    activeItem: state.toggleDivReducer
  }
}
```

And then the usage to be like

```
{item.sub && <div style={{display: this.props.activeMenu.id == item.id && !this.props.activeItem.hidden  ? 'block' : 'none'}}><Nest itemized={item.sub} /></div>}
```

---

There are probably other solutions to the problem than just these, but now you know the cause, you can investigate those for yourself.

As always, the exact names of variables are entirely up to you, I just picked something that made sense to me.

Comment: Thankyou for detailed explanation, will understand and implement and get back to you.Thanks again.

Comment: @Harsh how are you going with it?

Comment: Thanks alot , I have implemented the 1st solution and it works as expected ,ok now I understand it was a blunder, will implement 2nd as well and ask if any doubts

Comment: Thanks alot , I have implemented the 1st solution and it works as expected ,ok now I understand it was a blunder what I was doing , one query I had how the this.props.visibleItems[item.id] will find which id is clicked, is it because on action I have dispatched the id , is that the reason ,please could you explain me the flow,actually I am new to React,THANKS

Comment: Yes, the reason `this.props.visibleItems[item.id]` works is because the action has the `id` of the item that was toggled.  In fact, the whole solution is held together by the `id`.  When the reducer handles the action, it only toggles the the state for the specified `id`.  When rendering the item, it uses the `id` to get the visibility specific to that `item` only.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help